# Passing Joomla Module Parameters values into XML File

Tags: xml, flash, joomla, module

I am trying to doing a flash banner module, where all the images, url and text are fed
from a xml file.
We would like to keep them as parameters, so we enter the image details on the backend, and it
can automatically get into the XML and then show on the flash banner.

Please provide any solution or guidence to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_XML_output . You could very likely adapt this to use with http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JFile/write to create the XML file.